# String together multiple commands at command line - Qgis

Tags: qgis, command-line

I am using the command line to export images from Qgis. is there a way to export a series of images in a single command? It takes a while for the data to load each time. I have tried simply including a second snapshot command, but it only generated the second image.

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS-2~1.1\bin\qgis --project Z:\Projects\Virtual-Raleigh\QGIS\Raleigh.qgs --snapshot Z:\Projects\Virtual-Raleigh\Images\OSM-0794.png --width 4096 --height 4096 --extent 2090000,740000,2100000,750000